# Is there a way to put Express.Multer.File into a FormData object?

Tags: javascript, file, multipartform-data, multer

I need help on finding how to put a file with a type Express.Multer.File into a FormData object.

Context: I'm receiving a file with a type Express.Multer.File (I'm using nestjs, so I used this part of the documentation : https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload) that I need to put in a FormData, to send it to another API.

I tried form.append('randomword', file); but I get the following error :

```
TypeError: source.on is not a function
    at Function.DelayedStream.create (xxx/delayed-stream/lib/delayed_stream.js:33:10)
    at FormData.CombinedStream.append (xxx/combined-stream/lib/combined_stream.js:45:37)
...
```

I clearly sense that I'm doing it the wrong way, but I'm kinda lost on how to achieve something like this.

Could someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a "workaround" for this method.

- First, I get the file with the type Express.Multer.File.
- Then I save    it using createWriteStream from fs.
- Finally, I pass it into the    FormData object using createReadStream.

And done !
It isn't the best way to do this, but kind of a workaround, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use buffer and originalname obtained from multer to create a new Form Data.

For example, this would be the solution when you have only one file sent via POST method:

```
router.post("/", multer().single("file"), async (req, res, next) => {

let data = new FormData();
data.append("yourFormDataKey", req.file.buffer, req.file.originalname)

//HERE GOES YOUR CODE WHERE YOU USE THE FORM DATA CREATED//

}
```